# encontrar valores repetidos no vetor em c

Tags: c, array

Preciso criar um codigo que dado um vetor de numeros ele precisa verificar onde contem valores repetidos e subtrair 1 no tamanho do vetor sempre que encontra, porem ele esta dando erro de tempo limite dependendo do tamanho das entradas, alguem sabe uma forma mais otimizada de escrever o codigo??

```
int main()
{
   int N, tam;
   scanf("%d", &N);
   int nums[N];
   tam=N;
   
   for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
       scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
       
   for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
       for(int j=i+1; j<N; ++j){
           if(nums[i]==nums[j]){
               tam--;
           }
       }
   }
   
   printf("%d", tam);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se você ordernar os valores dá para fazer em n * log n. E se você se der ao trabalho de construir um hashset em C, dá para resolver em n.

Comment: ordenar os valores é mais trabalho que encontrar o número de duplicados. O mesmo vale para cria um hashset. E ainda terá que contar e/ou identificar os duplicados. Assim não deve valer a pena.,,

Answer (score 1):

Sobre seu programa

```
    int N, tam;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int nums[N];
```

Não use essa construção. Mesmo que em algum caso seja possível. No oficial declare um tamanho fixo ou use `malloc()` e crie do tamanho de que precisa, como

```
    #define T 20
    int outro[T]; // T é fixo

    // vetor vai de vetor[0] ate vetor[Q-1]...
    int Q = 20;
    int *vetor = (int *)malloc(Q * sizeof(int)); // vetor de 20 int
    free(vetor); // apaga o vetor
```

Teste sempre o retorno de `scanf()`. Que adianta seguir se não ler nada para `N`?

Não entendi a lógica do que está fazendo. Precisa contar os duplicados, mas está alterando `tam` onde salvou o tamanho do vetor...

Não escreva um programa interativo. Só vai perder tempo. Use constantes ou gere o valor na hora. Não há sentido em perder tempo inventando números a cada teste.

#### Exemplos

Se precisa apenas do total de duplicados acho que pode usar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int teste[] = {1,2,3};
    int dup     = 0;
    int init    = 0; // o primeiro indice
    int N       = sizeof(teste)/sizeof(int);

    for (int L = 0; L < N-1; L += 1)
        for (int R = L + 1; R < N; R += 1)
            if (teste[L] == teste[R])
            {   dup += 1;
                break;
            }
    printf("duplicados = %d\n", dup);
    return 0;
}
```

E se precisa do vetor com os elementos únicos pode usar algo como

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void show(int[], int, const char*);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int teste[20];
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\
\nentre com os elementos do vetor ao chamar o programa!\n\n");
        return - 1;
    }
    if (argc > 21) argc = 20;
    int N = argc - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i += 1) teste[i] = atoi(argv[1+i]);
    int dup     = 0;
    int size    = N;

    show(teste, size, "Vetor original");
    for (int L = 0; L < (N - 1); L += 1)
    {
        for (int R = N - 1; R > L; R -= 1)
        {
            if (teste[L] == teste[R])
            {
                if (R != N - 1) teste[R] = teste[N - 1];
                N -= 1, dup += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d elementos duplicados\n", dup);
    show(teste, N, "Elementos unicos");
    return 0;
}

void show(int v[], int n, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%d elementos: ", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) printf("%d ", v[i]);
    printf("\n");
};
```

#### Rodando esse exemplo

```
so> p3

entre com os elementos do vetor ao chamar o programa!


so> p3 1 2 3 4
Vetor original
4 elementos: 1 2 3 4
0 elementos duplicados
Elementos unicos
4 elementos: 1 2 3 4

so> p3 1 2 3 4 4
Vetor original
5 elementos: 1 2 3 4 4
1 elementos duplicados
Elementos unicos
4 elementos: 1 2 3 4

so> p3 1 1 2 3 4
Vetor original
5 elementos: 1 1 2 3 4
1 elementos duplicados
Elementos unicos
4 elementos: 1 4 2 3

so> p3 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
Vetor original
7 elementos: 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
3 elementos duplicados
Elementos unicos
4 elementos: 1 2 3 4

so> p3 1
Vetor original
1 elementos: 1
0 elementos duplicados
Elementos unicos
1 elementos: 1

so>
```

A noção de duplicado precisa de uma definição mais formal